# visualStudio openframeworksについてです

Tags: c++, visual-studio, openframeworks

openframeworksで顔合成をしようと思っていますが、下のようなエラーが出て上手くいきません

> 2>ContourFinder.obj : error LNK2019: 未解決の外部シンボル "float __cdecl ofxCv::trackingDistance(class cv::Rect_ const &,class cv::Rect_ const &)" (?trackingDistance@ofxCv@@YAMABV?$Rect_@H@cv@@0@Z) が関数 "public: virtual class std::vector > const & __thiscall ofxCv::Tracker >::track(class std::vector,class std::allocator > > const &)" (?track@?$Tracker@V?$Rect_@H@cv@@@ofxCv@@UAEABV?$vector@IV?$allocator@I@std@@@std@@ABV?$vector@V?$Rect_@H@cv@@V?$allocator@V?$Rect_@H@cv@@@std@@@4@@Z) で参照されました。
>
> 2>ObjectFinder.obj : error LNK2001: 外部シンボル ""float __cdecl ofxCv::trackingDistance(class cv::Rect_ const &,class cv::Rect_ const &)" (?trackingDistance@ofxCv@@YAMABV?$Rect_@H@cv@@0@Z)" は未解決です。
>
> 2>bin\day4_debug.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 件の未解決の外部参照

上記のエラー修正方法がわかりません。
よろしければ詳しく教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージ自体は割とよく見るリンカの設定ミスの際のものです。
使用しているライブラリファイルのパス設定が間違っている可能性が高いと思われます。
パス設定を見直してみてはどうでしょうか。